# As3 refer to Array positions using tags instead of numbers?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Is there a way to make an array composed of "tags", so I can refer to them by their "name"?

So usually when I want to refer to a position in my array I would do something like:

```
MyArray:Array = new Array( ["Marco", 26, "Portugal" ] );
trace(MyArray[2]);
Output: "Portugal"
```

I want to use an array where the positions have diferent names. So I wanted to be something like:

```
MyArray:Array = new Array( ["Marco", 26, "Portugal" ] );
trace(MyArray[Country]);
Output: "Portugal"
```

I'm pretty sure "tag" or "name" of the array isnt the propper term to use, but I don't know the correct one, so excuse me on that. Its also probably a easy question, but something that I never needed to use untill now. I'm building a "Area" array with positions, heigths and widths of several movieclips on stage, so I could use some simplification of the array to avoid always using numbers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use the `Object` class, it is the simplest way to use associative arrays in as3:

```
var ob:Object = {
  name: "Marco",
  age: 26,
  country:"Portugal"
};

trace(ob.country);
//output: Portugal
```

I recommend you to check this article on Adobe's website for further info: [ActionScript 3 fundamentals: Associative arrays, maps, and dictionaries](http://www.adobe.com/es/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/associative-arrays.html)

Answer (score 0):

While, I see you are using Array, it's no way to give a name for every element.

I suggest you the "Map" data struct in AS3。

```
var DC:Dictionary=new Dictionary;
DC["Country"] = "Portugal";
DC["name"] = "Marco";
...
```

Hope this will help you.